# convert linux code to windows code

Tags: java, linux, windows

I write a program in java and I want to run and show the result of following commands (top -n 1, run /bin/ls/) in windows.

```
String s = null;
ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
try {

    // run the Unix  command

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1");

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        outputs.add(s);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

I got the following error

```
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "top": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at code.ExecuteCommands.execute(ExecuteCommands.java:24)
    at code.Server.process(Server.java:61)
    at code.Server.main(Server.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Download and install cygwin for some linux integration in windows.

Comment: this has nothing to do with java. You're executing external programs, and seem to think that linux executables have 1:1 matches in Windows...

Comment: Report it as a bug to Microsoft. Works fine on Mac(s) and Linux. ;-)

Comment: man, it is incompatible to execute same command both in Linux and windows...this is the basic step to become a programer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to run the program called 'top' which is commonly used under unix/linux/freebsd operating systems to display process listings and cpu usage output.

Vanilla Windows does not have a program that looks like top, but it does have a program that is called 'tasklist' that you can execute. The output is different but you may be able to use it all the same.

If you want to be able to invoke something that looks exactly like top, you could try installing a linux-like environment like cygwin.

Comment: how about "run file_address" command in Linux?

Comment: I'm not sure what that command is - could you provide a reference for what it is, what it does, etc? I've never heard of it, I can't find anything for it, and it sounds like something that might be specific to your environment.

Comment: I find the answer of my question, thank you.